# To check irreduciblitity

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $f_n(x)= x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\dots+x+1$ then show that $f_p(x^{p^{e-1}})$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$
>   for every positive number e and every prime number p

I think this might be true because of cyclotomic polynomial as these polynomials are irreducible over the rationals. But how to apply this result?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).